# How to provide Pagination in Data Tables with large dataframes using Dash

Tags: python-3.x, datatable, pagination, plotly, plotly-dash

I am currently using dash-1.0.1. I am creating a public dashboard which returns a detailed report in the form of Data Table. But the Data Table being huge I want to provide **Pagination** feature to the Data Table and a *show [no of entries]* dropdown to display the number of entries in the table on a page.

Is there any method by which this could be achieved?

Comment: did you figured the solution?

Comment: no @Madhi not yet!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It seems that the pagination option was added to the DataTable class, configurable using a number of parameters.

Based on the example given [here](https://dash.plotly.com/datatable/callbacks), I created a working demo of a DataTable with pagination, and with a dropdown allowing to select the number of entries:

```
import dash
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output
import dash_table
import dash_html_components as html
import dash_core_components as dcc
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/plotly/datasets/master/gapminder2007.csv')
df[' index'] = range(1, len(df) + 1)    
app = dash.Dash(__name__)    
PAGE_SIZE = 15    

app.layout = html.Div([    
    html.Div('Data table pagination test'),    
    dcc.Dropdown(    
        id='select_page_size',    
        options=[{'label': '5', 'value': 5}, {'label': '10', 'value': 10}, {'label': '15', 'value': 15}],    
        value=5    
    ),    
    html.Div(dash_table.DataTable(    
        id='datatable-paging',    
        columns=[{"name": i, "id": i} for i in df.columns],    
        data=df.to_dict("rows"),    
        page_size=PAGE_SIZE,    
        page_current=0,    
    ))    
])        

@app.callback(    
    Output('datatable-paging', 'page_size'),    
    [Input('select_page_size', 'value')])    
def update_graph(page_size):    
    return page_size

    
if __name__ == '__main__':    
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

**Note:** in previous versions `DataTable` received pagination settings as a dict:

```
dash_table.DataTable(
    ...
    pagination_settings={
        'current_page': 0,
        'page_size': PAGE_SIZE
    },
)
```

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: Doesnt work The `dash_table.DataTable` component (version 4.11.2) with the ID "events_table" received an unexpected keyword argument: `pagination_settings`

Comment: @NehaJirafe The solution did work for a previous version of dash, so the downvote was a bit uncalled for. I updated the code to support the most recent version of dash.  In the future - writing a helpful comment or even editing and updating the answer will contribute more to the community than simply downvoting an otherwise good solution.